# Django reverse OneToOne .create() access

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Is there any way to .create() using a reverse lookup from a model with a OneToOneField?

Just as an example:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.Charfield()

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
```

How would I trigger create on the profile? `user.profile.create()` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Profile.objects.create(user=user)
```

This would create the userprofile.

This way, you can also check if a profile already exists. Something like this:

```
profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
```